# What should I do if I delete the redis vm file?

Tags: redis, virtual-machine

**Now the redis can not background save.**
I just want to dump it and restart.

How could I dump the redis? I've always this error :

> "Can't re-open the VM
>   swap file: /tmp/redis.swap. Exiting."

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the `dump.rdb` file. (or simply move it somewhere e.g ~/saved-rdb/., where redis-server won't find it.)
2. Start `redis-server`

**Note**: dump.rdb is your data. By deleting it you are starting fresh (meaning data lost).